# Difference in File object between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-chrome

There occurs a difference in the File object received from the same HTML input element between Chrome and Firefox. I am using Angular on the front-end.

My HTML Input Element

`<input type="file" accept=".csv" (change)=onSelectFile($event) />`

My Typescript Code

```
onSelectFile(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
}
```

The output of the above Typescript Code on **Mozilla Firefox 89.0.1 (64-bit)**

```
File { name: "Facility (5).csv", lastModified: 1624430723623, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 125, type: "text/csv" }
```

The output of the same Typescript Code on **Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

```
File { name: "Facility (5).csv", lastModified: 1624430723623, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 125, , type: "", lastModifiedDate: Wed Jun 23 2021, 12:15:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) }
```

As can be seen from the above console logs, the File object returns different parameters in different browsers. The type of the file is available in firefox as `text/csv` but not in chrome.

I have subsequent logic that depends upon the type of the file inputted/imported here. So, I need the `type` to have the file type on every browser. Please help.

(Note: I also want this work on Safari, but haven't tested it yet.)

Comment: I can't replicate this on the same browser version of Chrome. Selecting a csv file yields the type `application/vnd.ms-excel` for me. (And yes, it is actually a csv, not an xls(x).) https://jsfiddle.net/7vpLbhfq/

Comment: @Ivar do you think there might be a problem with the way I save the file on Excel? I selected regular CSV (Comma Delimited). I am aware that there are other options for CSV. Should I select any one of those? Which one did you save it as?

Comment: I'm not sure if the content of the file has any influence at all. You can try to create a plain new text file with the content of `1,2,3,4,5`, save it and then change the extension to `.csv`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to mention that, that is exactly how the file is first created. I then modify the file using Excel, save and try to upload the same. Here is a sample file https://my-stackoverflow.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Facility+(5).csv . So, do you think I shouldn't be creating the CSV in this manner?

Comment: And does the initial file show the type correctly? The sample file you provided gives me the same result (`application/vnd.ms-excel`).

Comment: Nope it shows text/csv for me. Even tried creating a new one from Excel. So, what exact format did you use for creating the file you inputted in your jsfiddle? Excel Workbook?

Comment: No, exactly the way I described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095041/difference-in-file-object-between-firefox-and-chrome#comment120355083_68095041). It could be related to the OS or its configuration. Can't help you much further I'm afraid.

Comment: According to MDN, the type is only based on the extension of the file, not how it is created. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type#example